# Tradingview’s Pine: comparison operator alert

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Code below records the lowest and the highest value since the script is started and calculates percentages of these, in comparison to the current value of the active bar. For the alert, a certain minimal value of difference shall be reached. This works fine for the bull, but the alert for the bear fires off immediately, regardless of its value. What’s wrong?

```
var float topp = 0
var float bott = close

if barstate.isrealtime
    if high > topp
        topp := high
    if low < bott
        bott := low

bull = 1 - close / topp
bear = 1 - bott / close

plot(topp)
plot(bull)
plot(close)
plot(bear)
plot(bott)

alertcondition(bull > 0.05 or bear > 0.05, title = " ", message = " ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you are using the first close to initialize `bott`, it could probably be less than the current `close` and the current `low`, so its value is used in realtime. In this case, when you calculate `bear` you get a value greater than 0.05.
You need to initialize `bott` to a large value that is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the current `low`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
var float topp = na
var float bott = na

if barstate.isrealtime
    topp := na(topp) ? 0 : topp
    bott := na(bott) ? close : bott

    if high > topp
        topp := high

    if low < bott
        bott := low

bull = 1 - close / topp
bear = 1 - bott / close

plot(topp)
plot(bull)
plot(close)
plot(bear)
plot(bott)

alertcondition(bull > 0.05 or bear > 0.05, title = " ", message = " ")
```